# Traversing the DOM using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Upon a click on an IMG, I would like to get to the next subsequent DIV so that the DIVs content can either be displayed or hidden depending on its current display state.

This is an HTML snippet:

```
<div>
  <span class="expand"><img src="images/plus.gif"></span>
  <span>Subject Heading</span>
</div>
<div class="record hidden">Display or Hide this text</div>
```

I have some code ([provided in another answer on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123401/using-jquery-to-find-the-next-table-row#123518)) for doing this in a table. Would I set an event listener for the img or the containing span? not sure how to use parent(), next(), sibling() functions to get around....

Also, how do you test if your navigation is getting to the right element? can you use an alert to display the id or value?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ is a useful guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="expand"><img src="x.jpg"></span>
  <span>Subject Heading</span>
</div>
<div class="record hidden">Display or Hide this text</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.expand img').toggle(
        function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().next().hide();
        },
        function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().next().show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that I'm using parent twice because the event is added to the image, whose parent is the span, whose parent is the div.

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner approach is to toggle the image's parent's class between collapsed and expanded then in your css you can use contextual selectors to hide nested divs within collapsed ones.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: took some thought and a subsequent answer's confirmation to get what you were referring to....I agree and I will explore this type of solution...thanks for the post

Answer (score 1):

One good place to look is in the Visual jQuery Docs under selectors: http://screencasts.visualjquery.com/

I think you're trying to do something like

$(this).parent().next('.hidden');

inside your onClick function?

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Allain is correct, it is better to operate only on the parent, then use CSS selectors to show or hide the children, flip +/- images, etc.  But anyway, [here](http://rome.purepistos.net/tmp/sof-269632.html) is functional code that does what you want in the way you were wondering:

```
<html>

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '.expand img' ).click(
            function() {
                $(this).parents( 'div' ).eq( 0 ).siblings( '.record' ).eq( 0 ).toggleClass( 'hidden' );
            }
        );
    } );
  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <span class="expand"><img src="http://stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png"></span>
    <span>Subject Heading</span>
  </div>
  <div class="other">Don't care about this</div>
  <div class="record hidden">Display or Hide this text</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you're worried about graceful degradation, you'll want to add a <noscript> block with <style>.hidden { display:block; }</style> in it. Note that, unfortunately, linking to a 'noscript.css' file inside a noscript block doesn't work, it has to be embedded in the <head>.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using currently, thanks Adam...but I will explore Allain's suggestion as well.

```
$(function(){
$('.expand img').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().next().show();
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/minus.gif') ;
    },
    function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().next().hide();
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/plus.gif') ;
    });
});
```

Comment: fwiw, I up-voted Allain's suggestion because it sounds good. I think he should provide a code example, though.

Comment: The trouble with this solution is that you are stuck with exactly the nesting depth and sibling relationship you have in your example.  If you ever nest deeper (great grandparent div?), or add or reorder siblings (see my example), your code must be adjusted.

Comment: My solution works regardless of sibling order, or ancestor distance.

Comment: the real trouble is that I didn't do a good job of asking my question. this solution will always suit my needs for my current project. I will (and have) returned to these answers to learn further concepts. I did upvote Pistos' answer and will review it in the future. thanks for all the answers

Comment: CarolinaJay65:  Thank you for posting your solution.  I'm just starting with jQuery/HTML/CSS and this worked really well.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

```
$('.expand').click(function () {
  $(".record").toggle();
});
```

or

```
$('.expand').click(function () {
  $(".record").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Though if you're going to be targeting the next div based on it's relevance to the clicked img, then you'll need to target it with .parent('span').parent('div').next('record')

Comment: I think he needs to apply the toggling to the next record not all of them.